# Autogenerate primitive codeblocks for ruby in vim

Tags: ruby, vim

When looking at screen cast like "destroy all software" or "railscast" it seems the authors are using some kind of tool to auto generate blocks of code like for instance if statements, for loops and more. Do anyone have knowledge of the name of such a tool or what it is called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are called *snippets*; they are like the built-in `:abbreviate` on steroids, usually with parameter insertions, mirroring, and multiple stops inside them. One of the first, very famous (and still widely used) is [snipMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540), a plugin inspired by TextMate; unfortunately, it's not maintained any more. A more modern variant (that requires Python though) is [UltiSnips](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2715). There are more, see [this list on the Vim Tips Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Category%3aAutomated_Text_Insertion).

There are two things to evaluate: First, the features of the snippet engine itself, and second, the quality and breadth of snippets provided by the author or others.

Answer (score 5):

I don't use snippets and only have one key mapped to insert something special (C-l in insert mode inserts " => "; see [my vimrc](https://github.com/garybernhardt/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc#L116)). I have tab [mapped](https://github.com/garybernhardt/dotfiles/blob/master/.vimrc#L126) to conditionally do completion (Vim maps this to C-p by default). In Destroy All Software, everything you see is recorded live while I talk and, other than the C-l exception and the built-in Vim identifier completion, it's all typed one character at a time.

Comment: About what you said of muscle memory this is rather nice to have as well. Not sure if you use something similar.

" Ctrl-A, Ctrl-E Home and End bash style in vim "
cnoremap <C-A> <Home>
cnoremap <C-E> <End>